# How to control browser back button in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I am developing a registration form using angular 8, At start it is in editable format, the next stage is to review our entered data so that it becomes readonly format, but when I moved from review state to input state by using browser back button it remains in same readonly format, but i need it in editable format, Kindly Provide me a Solution

Comment: Is this in a stepper? Is each stage a separate URL route?

Comment: yes , it a stepper and it's a single page application

Comment: But when click to go to the next item in the stepper, does it change the URL? Getting a back button to behave in a SPA is tricky, so I'm trying to get a good idea of how things are working currently.

Comment: No it is a SPA,so it doesn't change the URL but it changes the pages itself

Comment: In a SPA the url can be changed. Normally the url changed by the router. What back button you are talking about? The browser back button or a back button on your page?

Comment: Browser back button